# Hiding Counter in Mail App Mailbox List

Tags: mail.app

I got many Junk mails and they show up on the mailbox list counter in the macOS Mail app. I do not want any counter for Junk mail like I do not want to be notified by them at all. I added a picture for clarifying the problem. I do not want that 1 number near Junk Mail.
I used to use the Microsoft Outlook app and there was no such problem. Outlook app does not have any counter for Junk mail by default.

Thanks for any help,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Simplest would be 'Mark All Messages as Read' for Junk folder and this number will disappear... until next junk arrives.

Comment: So you mean there is no setting to get rid of this forever, just repeating the same thing over and over again?

Comment: No. It just simplest. Little bit more complicated would be creating rule: Condition - 'Message is junk mail' , action - 'Mark as Read' (haven't tested though)

Comment: Yes, I tried that one and selected it as "Mark as Read" and restarted, but still the same issue, anyways, thanks for helping :)

Comment: @Redarm How do you do that? I am asking that

Comment: @MertSaner You've clarified your question with more screenshots including their headings, so I withdraw my comment.